# select data based on how much time has passed since created_at

Tags: mysql

So lets say i have a resource Book. Book has `created_at` date in it and `published_at` as well. how can i perform a query which will return only books that have been published within two weeks after being created in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your timestamp is formated correctly in created_at you could probably do something like this

```
select * from books where published_at > created_at and published_at < DATE_ADD(created_at,INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```